# Accessing unicode value of char in string directly

Tags: java

I am working on project and I want to access ASCII value of string at some index 
But I don't want access `char` at index and parse it to integer.

Example:

```
char character = s.charAt(8);    
int ASCII = (int) character;
```

Is there any other way to do same without converting to char? And what will be time complexity?

Is there any built in function in java?
I don't know how char store in memory please anyone can explain me?
and how to handle Unicode without converting to `char`?

Thanks!!

Comment: `Is there any other way to do same without converting to char?` Try writing a `Java` program without a text editor and compiling it without a compiler.

Comment: Character stores as an unsigned 16-bit value so you grabbing the character from the String and casting it to an int is probably the easiest and fastest way to do it.

Comment: Sounds like http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization (even if there is nothing to optimize)

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is already a 16bit numerical type, whose value is interpreted as the code point of the character being displayed. when you cast it to `(int)`, there is no parsing involved at all and the complexity is O(1), absolutely. Just do as you wrote in your question.

If you strictly needed ASCII (or any other specific encoding), then you should use `getBytes` like:

```
byte character = s.getBytes("ASCII")[8]
int ASCII = (int) character;
```

Or even the first line only. Please be aware that non-ASCII-representable characters might get replaced when getting bytes. Also consider that the index of what you are looking for might not be `8` if you used a multi-byte encoding.

My 2 cents: consider researching a better representation for your data than a `String`.